# umbraco 7 membership property drop down list stores wrong value

Tags: .net, asp.net-membership, umbraco7

I added a drop down list property to the members section in umbraco 7. It has 3 values, which when viewing source are:

```
<option value="0">something</option>
<option value="1">something2</option>
<option value="2">something3</option>
```

yet when its stored , the values are stored as 108,107, 106.

I can just use those 3 values when referencing it in the future, but it seems like something not working as it should.

Has anyone seen this issue before?

Edited to add more from source

```
<select name="dropDownList" class="umb-editor umb-dropdown ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid" ng-switch-default="" ng-model="model.value" ng-options="item.id as item.value for item in model.config.items">
<option value="" class=""></option>
<option value="0">No Appraisal</option>
<option value="1" selected="selected">Monthly</option>
<option value="2">Quarterly</option>
<option value="3">Yearly</option>
</select>
```

Screen shot of membership property page
[image: membership properties]

Comment: Can you give some more details because its not fully clear. Can you post some screenshots about the dropdown property, the actually source, ...

Comment: added some more more info

Comment: I have some more questions: What are you trying to do here? 
Which dropdown data-type did you choose in the developer section?
What are the values you get when debugging?

Comment: Is the dropdown a standard Umbraco dropdown, or a custom property editor that you've made/installed yourself?